# Is it possible to apply syntax highlighting of one filetype to another in Visual Studio Code, like in Notepad++?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ide, notepad++, syntax-highlighting

Somebody who used Notepad++ clearly knows about applying custom syntax highlighting to any text, by selecting an option from the "Language" menu, as shown the screenshot below;

[image: screenshot]

This way, one can highlight the text, as he wish. I would like to know, is there any similar mechanism in **Visual Studio Code** editor, so that I can manually highlight the text even if its not done automatically.

Thanks.

Comment: click on the language field in the Statusbar and select a different language, if you want it done automatic use `fileassociations` setting to change language based on extension

Comment: Thanks @rioV8 , it works. Please post this as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the Language used for a particular instance by clicking on the Language ID field in the Status bar and select the new language from the list.

This executes the command `workbench.action.editor.changeLanguageMode` or `Change Language Mode` from the Command palette.

To do a permanent Language ID selection based on the file extension define a setting

```
  "files.associations": {
    "*.myext": "html",
    "*.myfoo": "css"
  }
```